# UWP - How to bind a Xaml Path within ToggleButton to the ToggleButton's Foreground Color

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a toggle button that contains a xaml path.

I want to set the fill color of the path to the foreground color of the toggle button, so that when the button is not pressed its black, when its pressed its white.

```
        <ToggleButton>
            <Path Data="M5.08333,4.5 L10.8333,4.33333 L17.3749,8.24242 L6.97926,10.6125 C6.97926,10.6125 7.35392,5.18685 5.08333,4.5 z" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="6.291" Stretch="Fill" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="12.292"/>
        </ToggleButton>
```

How can I do this>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [`ControlTemplate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/control-templates) for the [`ToggleButton`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299157.aspx),and then configure `Fill` property for `shapes` where in each `VisualState`.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ToggleButtonWithShapes" TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <Border
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
            <Grid>
                <Path
                    x:Name="shapes"
                    Width="60"
                    Height="20"
                    Data="M5.08333,4.5 L10.8333,4.33333 L17.3749,8.24242 L6.97926,10.6125 C6.97926,10.6125 7.35392,5.18685 5.08333,4.5 z"
                    Fill="Black"
                    Stretch="Fill"
                    UseLayoutRounding="True" />
            </Grid>
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Target="shapes.Fill" Value="White" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="CheckedPressed">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Target="shapes.Fill" Value="Black" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks for ths. This works, but I loose all the default animations this way. What do I need to do to keep those animations?

Comment: @ariqyad You can refer to  [ToggleButton styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299157.aspx),and create `Storyboard` for each VisualState.

Answer (score 0):

You need change VisualStates in your ToggleButton's style.

Comment: How do I refer to my path from a VisualState?